# Filtering by price not working in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, user-input, shopping-cart

I expect the list of products will change after I slide the slider, but nothing happened. The list still the same.

Main component:

```
import Left from "./Left"
import Content from "./Content"
import Categories from "../store/Categories"
import { useState } from "react"

const Main = ()=>{
    const[data, setState] = useState(Categories);

    const filterPrice = (price)=>{
        const result = Categories.filter((curData)=>{
            return curData.price <= price*1000000;
        });
        setState(result);
    }

    return(
        <div className="row  my-4 mx-2">
        <Left 
        onSlider = {() => filterPrice}
        />
        <Content array={data}/>
        
        </div>
       
    )
}

export default Main
```

Left component:

```
 import classes from "./Left.module.css"
 import { useState } from "react";

 const Left = props =>{
    const [value, setValue] = useState(20);
    var nf = new Intl.NumberFormat();
    const changeValue = (event) =>{
        const value = event.target.value
        setValue(value);
        props.onSlider(value);
    }
    return(
        <div className="col-sm-2 col-md-3 col-xl-2 border-right border-bottom position-relative">
            <div className="position-sticky">
                <article className="pb-3">
                            <h4>Price</h4>
                            <input
                            onChange={changeValue}
                            type="range"
                            className="price-filter"
                            min={0}
                            value={value}
                            max={100}
                            />
                            <p className={classes.price}>Value: {nf.format(value*1000000)}đ  </p> 
                 </article>
             </div>
        </div>
    );
 };

 export default Left;
```

I think the problem is the value of the input can't be passed to the Main component, where should I need to fix?

Comment: It looks like onSlider should be `onSlider={filterPrice}`, not `onSlider={() => filterPrice}`? Main issue is, as defined, moving the slider isn't actually invoking `filterPrice`.

Comment: Omg, it actually works! You're my savior man!